# Proving $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n+3}{n+1}=2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm trying to prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}x_n=2$, when $$x_n=\frac{2n+3}{n+1}$$

In other words, that this function converges to $f(x)=2$ on the interval $I=\Bbb{R^1}$. By the definition of convergence of a sequence, we have to find a natural number $N<n$ : $$-\epsilon+f(x)<\frac{2n+3}{n+1}<\epsilon+f(x)$$$$...$$ $$\frac{-\epsilon (n+1)+2n-1}{2}<n<\frac{\epsilon (n+1)+2n-1}{2}$$

Now we can choose the LHS here as $N$. This proves that $f(x_n)$ lies below the graphs of $f(x)+\epsilon$ and above the graph of $f(x)-\epsilon$, correct?

Comment: It may help to note that $\frac{2n+3}{n+1} = \frac{2n+2+1}{n+1}=\frac{2n+2}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+1}=2+\frac{1}{n+1}$

Comment: You can use $$\frac{2n+3}{n+1}=2+\frac1{n+1}$$ and prepare your proof using this expression instead.

Comment: It is very dangerous to use $f(x)$ instead of $L$. They might not coincide.

Comment: To follow up on Yves' point, a limit is *not* a function! It is a number.  Also, you're finding the limit of a *sequence*, not a series here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$|x_n-2|=\left|\frac1{n+1}\right|$$ and this is smaller than $\epsilon$ for all $n>N=\left\lceil\dfrac1{\epsilon}\right\rceil$.

Comment: Using this info, I got $N=\frac{1}{\epsilon}-1$. However, shouldnt any smaller value of $N$ be a valid answer as well?

Comment: My post says $N=\frac1\epsilon$, though I should have used $\lceil\frac1\epsilon\rceil$. The bound need not be tight.